# rspec not recording the mock object method call

Tags: ruby, rspec

My Method:

```
Module M1
def put_customer(somehash)

  customer = get_customer('unique id')
  if customer.nil?
    customer = Customer.new
  end  
  customer.str
  customer['attr1'] = somehash['attr1']
  customer['attr2'] = somehash['attr2']
  customer.save
end
```

Test:

```
context "#put_customer" do

  it "should save a new customer" do
    sample_hash = {...}
    mock_customer = double("mock_cusotmer", :[]= , :save => true, :str => "Mock Object")
    Customer.stub(:new).and_return(mock_customer)
    M1.stub(:get_customer).and_return(nil)
    M1::put_customer

    mock_customer.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
    mock_customer.should_receive(:[]=).exactly(2).times

  end
end
```

The problem is the mock_customer says it did not receive a call, although it prints "Mock Object" which makes me suspect that it did receive the mock object, although for some reason its not recording the mock call.
Failure : expected 1 time
          received 0 times.

Answer (score 0):

As shown, `put_customer` is an `M1` *instance* method and it's calling `get_customer` as an *instance* method. However, you're calling `put_customer` and have mocked `get_customer` as *module* or *class* methods.

In any event, assuming that `put_customer` is actually defined as a class/module method, the problem you're having is that you're setting your expectations *after* having called the code in question. Your `M1::put_customer` call needs to be placed *after* the `should_receive` expectations.